# How to put/get multiple JSONObjects to JSONArray?

Tags: java, json

Is it possible to store multiple different `JSONObject`s into a single `JSONArray`? This is the structure, I want to store in a `JSONArray`.

```
[{"value1":1,"value2":900,"value3":1368349},{"value1":2,"value2":1900,"value3":136856},{"value1":3,"value2":600,"value3":136845}]
```

Here's the code where I am setting `JSONObject` and putting it into a `JSONArray`

```
if(somecondition) {
  // putting values to json object
  jsonObj.put("value1", 1);
  jsonObj.put("value2", 900);
  jsonObj.put("value3", 1368349);
}
for(int i=0;i<=jsonArray.length();i++){
  jsonArray.put(jsonObj);
  appObj.setJsonAlarmArray(jsonArray);
  // appObj is object of Application Class
  editor= sharedPrefs.edit();
  editor.putString("key", jsonArray.toString());
  System.out.println(jsonArray.toString());
  editor.commit();
}
```

Using this code only the last value, which I am setting in JSON object Override to all objects. Any suggestions to achieve this?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I found very good link for JSON: http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/wiki/EncodingExamples#Example_1-1_-_Encode_a_JSON_object

Here's code to add multiple JSONObjects to JSONArray.

```
JSONArray Obj = new JSONArray();
try {
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        // 1st object
        JSONObject list1 = new JSONObject();
        list1.put("val1",i+1);
        list1.put("val2",i+2);
        list1.put("val3",i+3);
        obj.put(list1);
    }

} catch (JSONException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
}             
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ""+obj, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: I tried the same thing but only the last json object gets appended multiple times......i don't know what went wrong

Comment: its to late, but have you declare JSONObject outside to your for loop. @chopu

Answer (score 12):

Once you have put the values into the JSONObject then put the JSONObject into the JSONArray staright after.

Something like this maybe:

```
jsonObj.put("value1", 1);
jsonObj.put("value2", 900);
jsonObj.put("value3", 1368349);
jsonArray.put(jsonObj);
```

Then create new JSONObject, put the other values into it and add it to the JSONArray:

```
jsonObj.put("value1", 2);
jsonObj.put("value2", 1900);
jsonObj.put("value3", 136856);
jsonArray.put(jsonObj);
```

Comment: I am setting values in  JSONObject on Button click. so when second time button is clicked the values of JSONObjects automatically set. @Ash

Comment: @PSK It looks like I have not understood the question properly, can you explain a bit further of what you are trying to do?

Comment: I have found very good link for JSON. I have added my answer.@Ash

Comment: @PSK So you have answered your own question now, because if you have you should accept it.

Answer (score 0):

From android API Level 19, when I want to instance JSONArray object I put JSONObject directly as parameter like below:

```
JSONArray jsonArray=new JSONArray(jsonObject);
```

JSONArray has constructor to accept object.